# Algorithm for the function "drop" in a binary random-access list

Tags: algorithms, data-structures, functional-programming

In the book Purely Functional Data Structures by Okasaki, exercise 9.1 asks:

> Write a function `drop` of type `int x a' RList -> a' RList` that deletes the first *k* elements of a binary random-access list.  Your function should run in *O(log n)* time.

Using the features the author is using so far, i.e. a complete binary leaf tree and a dense representation, what does the algorithm look like?

It can't be a sequence of *k* calls to `unconsTree` because this would not run in *O(log n)*.

Comment: What have you tried?  What do you know?  Do you know how to delete a subtree in the binary tree (a single node in the binary tree and all nodes under it) in $O(\lg n)$ time?  Do you know how to express the first $k$ elements of the list as a union of subtrees?  How many subtrees does it constitute?

Comment: Please explain the notation from the book, not everyone has it handy. What's the definition of the `RList` type and what does `unconsTree` do?